# ContentVersion to File Attachment in Email | APEX

Tags: apex, trigger, contentversion, blob

I am trying to get the Blob Version Data from the ContentVersion in Apex class and send it in an Email using the Following Code:

```
 Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
      Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa1 = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
    if(typeo == 'SalesForce Error')
    {
         List<id> ContentDocumentids = new List<id>();

         for(contentDocumentLink CDLink : [SELECT LinkedEntityid, ContentDocumentid FROM contentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityid=:RecordID])
        {
           ContentDocumentids.add(CDLink.ContentDocumentid);  
        }
    
    /* GET Data for the image */
    ContentVersion cv = [SELECT title,PathOnClient, FileType,
                                                versiondata 
                                          FROM contentversion 
                                          WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :ContentDocumentids  
                                           ];
          Blob Data = cv.VersionData;
      
        if(Data.size()>0)
        {
          efa1.setBody(Data);
          efa1.setFileName(Cv.Title);
            
          Mail.fileattachments.add(efa1); // This line is throwing the Error 
        }
         
    }
```

I have confirmed that there is in fact a file related to the ID that's being sent out but for some reason it's giving me the following Error:

```
execution of AfterUpdate caused by System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

What am I doing wrong? am I using the wrong information for attachment

UPDATE--
Afer doing Checkpoints I see there is Data in CV, but Mail.addatt atchment isnt able to add, it keeps showing null values see image below:

[image]?

Comment: Which specific line is throwing the error?  Please [edit] your post to include more context -- is this a trigger?

Comment: your strategy is not correct -- you want the `LatestContentVersion` for the CDL's `ContentDocument`

Comment: @DavidCheng Thanks for asking me to add info, I have edited the question, showing the line and what am I using to make this process happen.

Comment: please use [edit] and properly format/indent your code

Comment: Hi @cropredy, I just added more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I figured it out, I was using a SingleEmailMessage object, and according to this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_sending_attachments.htm) I have to add an attachment using the following code:

```
email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});
```

instead of doing `Mail. attachment`

This worked!